# Is there a way to stretch Android phone apps in tablets like how Apple does when we install iphone app on Ipad?

Tags: android

I have designed a app to support Android phones and i didn't create any layouts or images to support tablets. After running the app in the tablet i see that there is a lot of empty space on tablets.I don't have time to create separate layouts for bigger screen devices. I'm just wondering if there is any way that android stretches screen to support tablet versions like how apple does when we install the Iphone app on Ipad.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: See [Supporting Tablets and Handsets](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

Comment: As i said I don't have time to create layouts for tablet now..I'm looking for some quick fix which i think is not available.